# Is this method returning a System.Object class an anti-pattern?

Tags: c#

I work an an automation team designing tests for electronic components. One thing our framework sorely needs is a single source point for our driver objects for the various pieces of test equipment at a workbench (right now, driver object creation is very wild-west).

Basically, the idea would be there would be one object, constructed based on a configuration file(s), which is the single place all other test code looks to to get the driver objects, based on a name string. I'll call it a "DriverSource" here.

The problem is, these drivers do not present similar interfaces at all. One might be a power supply (with methods like "SetVoltage" and "SetCurrentLimit"), while another might be a digital multimeter (with methods like "ReadVoltage" or "ReadCurrent").

The best solution I've come up with is to have a method with the following declaration:

```
public object GetDriver(string name);
```

Then, the test code using my "DriverSource" object would call that method, and then cast the System.Object to the correct driver type (or more accurately, the correct driver interface, like IPowerSupply).

I *think* casting like that is acceptable because whatever test code is about to use this driver had better know what the interface is. But I was hoping to get some input on whether or not this is an anti-pattern waiting to bite me. Any better pattern for solving this issue would also be greatly appreciated.

A final note: I think this is obvious, but performance is essentially a non-issue for this problem. Fetching the drivers is something will happen less than 100 times in a test run that can last hours.

Comment: The phrase "Basically, the idea would be there would be one object, constructed based on a configuration file(s)" gives away that unfortunate truth that you'll give up at least some degree of type-safety to be able to do that. Maybe someone can prove my assumption wrong - I'd love to see it.

Comment: It might be possible for this central object to be able to search for drivers by type, instead of name. So, instead of `GetDriver(string name)`, you'd have `GetDriver<T extends Driver>`(). The Unity game engine does something like this.

Comment: generics, `dynamic`  would be better... Depending on what you actually care about...

Comment: @Katana314 It would need to at least somehow take a name or some similar concept into account, because there can be more than one of each driver. For example, our benches have 3 power supplies.

Comment: Seems like you are looking for the [Service Locator Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648968.aspx). For example, [Common Service Locator's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommonServiceLocator/)  [IServiceLocator](https://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#main/Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation/IServiceLocator.cs) implementation.

Comment: Well, it would be possible to do both. If you look up the `@Autowired` annotation in Spring (for Java) it works this way, somewhat. You can refer to just a type and it will use that type if only one exists, or you can provide it an identifier name. C# LINQ expressions can help you find objects in a list of a certain type (or you can optimize it by using a Dictionary)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you already know the type and you're going to cast to an interface or class anyway, a better approach would be to hand the method call a type parameter.

```
public T GetDriver<T>(string name);
```

You can then use a Factory pattern to return you an object of the appropriate type from the method.

```
public T GetDriver<T>(string name)
{
    switch(typeof(T).Name)
    {
        case "Foo":
            // Construct and return a Foo object
        case "Bar":
            // Construct and return a Bar object
        case "Baz":
            // Construct and return a Baz object
        default:
            return default(T);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var driver = GetDriver<Foo>(someString); // Returns a Foo object
```

Comment: To avoid that `switch` you can create a generic interface or base object for all your `T` objects and instantiate them by reflection.  That will help you to avoid to do changes to your `GetDriver<T>` method

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for! I didn't realize generics could be used on any method, thought it was for constructors only.

Comment: This doesn't even compile. You can't switch on types and a switch should have curly braces.

Comment: To be honest, I was planning on just casting inside the "GetDriver" method anyway. Ultimately, the code calling this "DriverSource" needs to ask for something consistent with the underlying configuration or there needs to be an exception (i.e. if you call 'var driver = GetDriver<IPowerSupply>("Multimeter"), you have to throw a runtime exception). But with the generics, I can deal with the error handling for that case in this one location (the GetDriver method), instead of just getting a InvalidCastException wherever I happen to do the casting in the test code.

Comment: @Enigmativity: OK, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to make this generic, I would use a factory pattern.

Lets start off by identifying the type structure:

```
public interface IDriver
{
}

public interface IPowerSupply : IDriver
{
    void SetVoltage();
    void SetCurrent();
}

public interface IMultimeter : IDriver
{
    double MeasureVoltage();
}
```

Which you can add to or remove from as needed. Now we need a way for the factory to auto-discover the correct types and provide the configuration information to it. So lets create a custom attribute:

```
public class DriverHandlerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type DriverType { get; set; }
    public string ConfigurationName { get; set; }
}
```

And then we need a place to store configuration data. This type can contain whatever you want, like a dictionary of keys/values that are loaded from configuration files:

```
public class Configuration
{
    public string DriverName { get; set; }
    public string OtherSetting { get; set; }
}
```

Finally we can create a driver. Lets create an `IPowerSupply`:

```
[DriverHandler(DriverType = typeof(IPowerSupply), ConfigurationName="BaseSupply")]
public class BasePowerSupply : IPowerSupply
{
    public BasePowerSupply(Configuration config) { /* ... */ }

    public void SetVoltage() { /* ... */ }

    public void SetCurrent() { /* ... */ }
}
```

The important part is that it is decorated with the attribute and that it has a constructor (although I created the factory so that it can use default constructors too):

```
public static class DriverFactory
{
    public static IDriver Create(Configuration config)
    {
        Type driverType = GetTypeForDriver(config.DriverName);
        if (driverType == null) return null;
        if (driverType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(Configuration) }) != null)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(driverType, config) as IDriver;
        else
            return Activator.CreateInstance(driverType) as IDriver;
    }

    public static T Create<T>(Configuration config) where T : IDriver
    {
        return (T)Create(config);
    }

    private static Type GetTypeForDriver(string driverName)
    {
        var type = (from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                    let attrib = t.GetCustomAttribute<DriverHandlerAttribute>()
                    where attrib != null && attrib.ConfigurationName == driverName
                    select t).FirstOrDefault();
        return type;
    }
}
```

So to use this, you would read in the configuration data (loaded from XML, read from a service, files, etc). You can then create the driver like:

`var driver = DriverFactory.Create(configuration);`

Or if you are using the generic method and you know the configuration is for a power supply, you can call:

`var driver = DriverFactory.Create<IPowerSupply>(configuration);`

And when you run your tests, you can verify that you get the right data back, for example, in your test method:

```
Assert.IsTrue(driver is IPowerSupply);
Assert.IsTrue(driver is BaseSupply);
Assert.DoesWhatever(((IPowerSupply)driver).SetVoltage());
```

And so-on and so-forth.

Comment: I think you could make this work with just an attribute like `[DriverHandler(ConfigurationName="BaseSupply")]`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yes, the other argument isn't used here but could be used in the factory to do some additional validation if needed, or removed completely.

Comment: This definitely looks useful for the actual creation of the drivers, but in the end, the factory returns an IDriver interface with no methods. (That is, unless I misunderstand something). In which case, I'm still back to the same issue of the test code calling the factory and then having to cast the IDriver to the specific driver it needs.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with this code:

```
public T GetDriver<T>(string name)
{
    return ((Func<string, T>)_factories[typeof(T)])(name);
}
```

The `_factories` object looks like this:

```
private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _factories = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>()
{
    { typeof(Foo), (Delegate)(Func<string, Foo>)(s => new Foo(s)) },
    { typeof(Bar), (Delegate)(Func<string, Bar>)(s => new Bar()) },
    { typeof(Baz), (Delegate)(Func<string, Baz>)(s => new Baz()) },
};
```

Basically the `_factories` dictionary contains all of the code to create each object type based on string parameter passed in. Note that in my example above the `Foo` class takes `s` as a constructor parameter.

The dictionary can also then be modified at run-time to suite your needs without needing to recompile code.

---

I would even go one step further. If you define this factory class:

```
public class Factory
{
    private Dictionary<Type, Delegate> _factories = new Dictionary<Type, Delegate>();

    public T Build<T>(string name)
    {
        return ((Func<string, T>)_factories[typeof(T)])(name);
    }

    public void Define<T>(Func<string, T> create)
    {
        _factories.Add(typeof(T), create);
    }
}
```

You can then write this code:

```
var drivers = new Factory();
drivers.Define(s => new Foo(s));
drivers.Define(s => new Bar());
drivers.Define(s => new Baz());

var driver = drivers.Build<Foo>("foo");
```

I like that even better. It's strongly-typed and easily customized at run-time.

Comment: Good suggestion... Also if got to that point using any of existing DI frameworks to deal with instantiation of objects and managing dependencies/configuration may be better choice than manually writing yet another one...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - I agree - I even wrote a fully fledged DI framework myself a few years back. There are plenty of good ones to choose from.